# How to plot a line graph with x and y data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have been trying to create a simple line-graph using Chart.JS to map out my data.

In my case, the data comes in the form that looks like this:

```
[[1452,100],[1330,100],[1307,100],[1105,100],[1071,200],[1261,100]]
```

Where the first entry in each piece is the x coordinate, and the second is the y coordinate.

In the examples shown in the chart.js documentation, the x coordinates are simply text labels:

```
var data = {
    labels: ["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing", "Coding", "Cycling", "Running"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100]
        }
    ]
};
```

What is the best way to plot the x and y data without simply generating an obscene number of labels (while the data in this case was 6 entries, in reality it would be thousands).

EDIT:

For clarity, I do not mean a scatter plot graph - the data is structured and will be, by virtue of where the data comes from, form a line. The x Axis will be in an order with no duplicate entries.

The data would look roughly like the below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make a scatter plot. None of the Chart.js examples show how to make scatter plots, because it doesn't have that ability. If you must use Chart.js, you could use a scatter plot add-on for it, like that available at https://dima117.github.io/Chart.Scatter/.

If you don't mind changing your plotting library, you might want to consider something like Highcharts, or Dojo Charting. There are plenty of options, but I find those two to be quite easy to use.

Comment: Nope, the structure of the data forms a perfect line with no overlaps. It is two sets of data that will appear roughly like this:
https://zeroblock.com/img/visual-depth.png

Comment: I know it's a misleading name, but scatter plots don't need to be scattered. A line plot like Chart.js has wants regular intervals between the x values, which you don't seem to have. If you have irregular intervals between your x values, then I think a scatter plot (where the points are joined by a line) is still your best bet.